# directory_name used for a particular schema

Tags: oracle

When I tried the query,

`SELECT owner, directory_name, directory_path  FROM all_directories;`

```
OWNER                          DIRECTORY_NAME                 DIRECTORY_PATH  
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------------
SYS                            MY_DIR_NAME                       E:\..... 
SYS                            OTHER_DIR_NAME1                   E:\..... 
SYS                            OTHER_DIR_NAME2                   E:\.....
```

Say, `MY_DIR_NAME` is the one I am using in my schema and is came listed under my 
schema hierarchy(`Connections->my_schema_name->Directories->MY_DIR_NAME`). My question is how can I know which one is used for my schema, 
with out searching the same in the `Directories` folder.Secondly, how can I grant permission to one `directory` under `other_schema_name`
to use in `my_schema_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `all_directories` (and its more powerful cousin, `dba_directories`) show the `OWNER` which can be confusing, because all directory objects are owned by `SYS`.

When you log in as a schema and query `all_directories` you are really seeing the directory objects for which the schema has some privileges (e.g. READ, WRITE).

You can grant permission with:

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY MY_DIR_NAME TO other_schema_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to find the directories which having `READ`, `WIRTE` privileges for a perticular schema.

```
SELECT grantor, grantee, table_schema, table_name, privilege
FROM all_tab_privs
WHERE grantee= '<SCHEMA_NAME>'
AND   privilege IN ('READ', 'WRITE');
```

Try the below query to grant `READ` & `WRITE` permissions to a directory.

```
GRANT read, write ON directory <directory_name> TO <schama_name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Directories** are database objects not owned by any particular user. That is one of the reason, you don't see `USER_DIRECTORIES`, analogous to other **USER_** views you have for other database objects.

For directories, you have `ALL_DIRECTORIES` and `DBA_DIRECTORIES`. The first one, lists the directories which you have access to.

You can simply use `GRANT` to grant privileges for a directory to another schema